# ALTER TABLE On Update change value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question. My database had two tables player, and items

Player have column `player_id` as `primary(auto increment)`, and have `player_head_equipment`, `player_body_equipment`

Items have column `item_id` as `primary(auto increment)`, and have `item_is_wearing` which has value of 0 if player dont wear item and 1 if player do.

How I can write sql command to table for auto update `item_is_wearing` depends of change in `player_body_equipment` ?

Comment: What you seem to want is called [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html) (the AFTER UPDATE variant probably)

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: its not a good practise but anyway here you can read about triggers in MySQL database https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html, or actually you can write one procedure where you will do some validate for both tables

Comment: Can you share DDLs of your tables? It kind of hard to follow the question as its currently worded.

Answer (score 0):

Create a trigger on table player. Whenever a row is inserted into table player your trigger will automatically execute and run whatever code you would like it to run.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER INSERT
   ON player FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   -- variable declarations

   -- trigger code
   --check if player_head_equipment or player_body_equipment exists 
   --in table items, if so update that row to 1 

END;
```

If you need more syntax help let me know.